# Is there a “right” way to Prototype functions in C++?

Tags: c++

I was taught to do:

```
functionReturn function(dataType_of_parameter)
```

While more and more I have been seeing

```
functionReturn function(dataType_of_parameter parameter_identifier)
```

Comment: The `parameter_identifier` tells people what the parameter is for. It is a good guide to memory.

Comment: Both of those will compile as prototypes. So, from a compiler perspective, both are "correct". However, putting the name of the parameter in there is good for documentation purposes, whereas omitting it really only saves a few keystrokes. So I think having `parameter_identifier` wins out.

Comment: Opinion, but I'm with the first two comments (not sure what the third's about). More information is almost always preferable to less.

Answer (score 5):

Both suggestions are right ways to declare a function. The argument names are optional and make no difference to the compiler except in the function definition.

The advantage of naming function arguments in forward declarations is that a programmer can deduce the the purpose of the argument. Consider for example `void copy(T* source, T* dest)` versus `void copy(T*, T*)`.

Comment: Why is source non-const?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont well, that cannot be deduced from the declaration. Hopefully the documentation will explain.

Comment: no, I won't be using a function named copy with a non-const pointer to source, so have no need for its documentation.